# Symmetric relation on set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question:**

> A relation $R$ is defined on the set $\mathbb Z$ (set of all integers) by “$aRb$ if
>   and only if $2a + 3b$ is divisible by $5$”, for all $a, b \in\mathbb Z$. Examine if $R$
>   is a symmetric relation on $\mathbb Z$.

**Solution:**

> Let $a, b \in\mathbb Z$ and $aRb$ holds i.e., $2a + 3a = 5a$, which is divisible by
>   $5$. Now, $2a + 3a = 5a – 2a + 5b – 3b = 5(a + b) – (2a + 3b)$ is also divisible by $5$.
>
> Therefore $aRa$ holds for all $a$ in $\mathbb Z$ i.e. $R$ is reflexive.

**My question:**

So it's saying that this relation is not symmetric, but reflexive. But I really don't get the logic behind this? Could you guys help me by breaking it down even more? Like, break it down enough that a child would understand it (me being the child).

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  You ask if $R$ is symmetric, but then you appear to check that it is reflexive instead.  And, to check that, you start by assuming you have $a,b$ with $aRb$ which you incorrectly say is the same as $2a+3a=5a$ (which does not even involve $b$).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! You must use $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ to write mathematical formulas. Edit your question to improve it.

Comment: This question has been asked before. See: [Proof of Equivalence Relation $R=\{(a,b)\in\Bbb N^2: 5\mid (2a+3b)\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653733/proof-of-equivalence-relation-r-a-b-in-bbb-n2-5-mid-2a3b).