# Prove that a relation is Equivalent where: $7\mid x+6y$ where x and y both come from a set of numbers (1,2,3.....10)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Like I've mentioned, I need to prove that it is **equivalent**, and get all of its classes.
Proving that it is Reflexive is super easy and I did it myself.
Proving **symmetry** and **transitivity** is what bothers me.
I don't even want to talk about **classes**, which I definitely do not know how to define.

***Thanks for your help in advance***

Comment: If you don't want to work with classes then perhaps you would find it easier to simply list all the equivalent pairs.  Then you could check for  symmetry and transitivity directly.

Comment: It would take me years to do it manually like that. I need to finish something like this within 15 minutes.

Comment: By *equivalent* do you mean an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)?

Comment: Years?  Seriously?  Even if you do it blindly there are only $100$ possible pairs to check, and each one takes only a second or two.  And, of course, you can be systematic about it.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I do

Comment: Notice that $6\equiv-1\pmod7$, so the reltion in the question amounts to $7|(x-y)$, which says $x\equiv y\pmod7$.

Comment: You could check older posts of similar type, for example: [Show that $R = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} : 4 \mid(5x+3y)\}$ is an equivalence relation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/934685) or [Proof of Equivalence Relation $R=\{(a,b)\in\Bbb N^2: 5\mid (2a+3b)\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2653733). (In general, it is useful to search a bit - to see whether some similar questions have been already asked.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint For transitivity**

Assume that
$$7\mid(x+6y)$$
and
$$7\mid(y+6z)$$

then

$$x+6y=7k$$
and
$$y+6z=7k'$$

So, the sum gives
$$x+6z=7(k+k'-y)=7k''$$

Other approach

$$x+6y\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
$$y+6z\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
$$-7y\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
the sum gives
$$x+6z\equiv 0 \mod 7$$
Done.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. Is there any way you could help me with classes?

Comment: How do I find the possible solutions for all different classes?

Comment: @OgnjenOgnjanovic Please have a look. I added some lines.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$\frac{x+6y}{7}\in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\pm\frac{x+6y}{7}+k\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. The right hand side is easier to use to show symmetry or transitivity.

Comment: I've got the symmetry done, but I've got no Idea how to prove transitivity now.

Comment: Assume $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ are in the relation and look at the sum of the appropriate fractions.